# Block/Unblock Ports using Python for Windows Possible? How?

Tags: python

I would like to create a very small firewall. I just want to be able to block/unblock IPs and Ports using it(so maybe its not an actual firewall, but a small component of it). I want to create this module using python for windows. Is it possible? If yes how do i proceed? Which libraries? Do i have to link windows firewall to python somehow or does a direct method exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can control Windows Firewall using this API: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I've never used this, and haven't had a need to make arbitrary calls to Windows libraries, so am unsure whether this will be if real use to you.